# There are 4 high severity vulnerabilities in TestCafe. How to fix them?

Tags: security, testcafe

I have started working with TestCafe 2.2.0

The Following was noted in the console.

```
up to date, audited 598 packages in 8s

72 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

4 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

How to fix the vulnerabilities?
`npm audit fix --force` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These vulnerabilities are already fixed in `testcafe@2.3.0-rc.2`.